# TypeScript type for nested arrays of functions

Tags: typescript, types, type-hinting

I have a terrible data structure that is causing TypeScript to freak out.

```
let foo = {
    'baz':[
        [[x1, x2, x3], (a: any, b: number, c: number) => 5],
        [[x4], (a: number) => 7]],
    'bar':[
        [[], () => 0]]
}
```

`x1, x2...` are all `(s: string) => number | string` functions. I'm struggling to explicitly define `foo's` type. In Java-esque terms, it would be

```
Map<String, List<Tuple<List<Function<String,Any>>, Function<Any...,Integer>>>>
```

A list of lists, where the inner list has a list of functions and a function. As an aside, the number of elements in the list of functions will always equal the number of parameters in the anonymous function. The TypeScript compiler recommends:

```
 Record<string, (any[] | ((...args: any) => number))[][]>
```

However, when I attempt to call `foo['baz'][0][0][2](myString)`, to call `x3(myString)`, the compiler yells

```
TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'number' can't be used 
to index type 'any[] | ((...args: any) => number)'.   No index signature with a parameter of 
type 'number' was found on type 'any[] | ((...args: any) => number)'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Record<string, [((operand: string) => (string | number))[], ((...v: any[]) => number)][]>
```

I found it.